# Run JavaScript without WebView

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have code in html:

```
function analyze(t){
    t=t.split("");
    t=t.slice(3);
    t=t.slice(2);
    return t.join("")
}
```

And i download this code from the internet(the code is changing and it make some changes on a string).

And i want to know if there is a way to run this code in C# without WebView and in synchronous.
The code is in javascript.

Comment: Why not just write it in C#?

Comment: Because i run a program that need to run some analyze on a string.And the analyze may change

Comment: surely it would be easier then to to write the string in C# and use compiler services to compile and execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) to execute JavaScript from .NET. It's a fully functional js interpreter providing functionality for calling js-Code from .NET and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft.JScript to evaluate JavaScript.

Here's an example on how to do that: http://odetocode.com/articles/80.aspx